# Codesigning Mac Project with subprojects from command line: a sealed resource is missing or invalid

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, xcodebuild

Create archive:

```
xcodebuild -archivePath MyApp -project /Users/dima/MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj -scheme MyApp archive
```

Ok, let's build .app:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat APP -archivePath MyApp.xcarchive -exportPath MyApp -exportSigningIdentity "Developer ID Application: MY NAME"
```

I got MyApp.app

But when I check app I got this message:

```
a sealed resource is missing or invalid
```

I got several subproject-frameworks dependencies, use Swift. And if I will make export archive by hand, all works and signed ok.

XCode 7 beta 3.

**Update**

Seems this problem related to fact that My project has other projects inside (frameworks). Test app without dependencies works fine.

Tries to update project to workspace and change script to use workspace seems not solve the problem

Comment: Did you unlock your keychain with `security unlock-keychain`?